# IntelliJ Idea 14: cannot resolve symbol spark

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, sbt

I made a dependency of Spark which worked in my first project. But when I try to make a new project with Spark, my SBT does not import the external jars of org.apache.spark. Therefore IntelliJ Idea gives the error that it "cannot resolve symbol". 
I already tried to make a new project from scratch and use auto-import but none works. When I try to compile I get the messages that "object apache is not a member of package org". My build.sbt looks like this:

```
name := "hello"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-parent_2.10" % "1.4.1"
```

I have the impression that there might be something wrong with my SBT settings, although it already worked one time. And except for the external libraries everything is the same...
I also tried to import the pom.xml file of my spark dependency but that also doesn't work.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `scalaVersion := "2.11.7"` possibly conflicts with `"spark-parent_**2.10**"`  try `spark-parent_2.11`

Comment: I have also been thinking this but this doesnt work. And it already worked with spark-parent 2.10...

Comment: Does it compile in terminal? Are you using default resolvers or some kind of proxy (Nexus, Artifactory)? What is the log output?

Comment: I also get this message:
SBT project import
           [warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.spark#spark-parent_2.11;1.4.1!spark-parent_2.11.jar(doc):  (0ms)
           [warn] ==== local: tried
           [warn]   C:\Users\Giselle\.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-parent_2.11\1.4.1\docs\spark-parent_2.11-javadoc.jar
           [warn] ==== public: tried
           [warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-parent_2.11/1.4.1/spark-parent_2.11-1.4.1-javadoc.jar
           [warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.spark#spark-parent_2.11;1.4.1!spark-parent_2.11.jar(src):  (0ms)

Comment: I dont use any resolvers (as far as I'm aware of)

Comment: I also get the error that he can't resolve the % symbols in the line of libraryDependencies

Comment: seems like sbt is trying to download *Javadoc* for spark-parent. Have you configured javadoc download in sbt or in idea import settings?

Comment: by the way the spark-parent repositories for both 2.10 and 2.11 seem to only contain tests. Additionally, [official spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#where-to-go-from-here) seems to indicate that the answers mentioning *spar-core* are most probably right.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me->

```
name := "ProjectName"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.1.0"
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. It seems the reason was that the `build.sbt` file was specifying the wrong version of scala.

If you run `spark-shell` it'll say at some point the scala version used by Spark, e.g.

```
Using Scala version 2.11.8
```

Then I edited the line in the `build.sbt` file to point to that version and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1"
```

in my `build.sbt` and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Currently [spark-cassandra-connector](http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/) compatible with Scala 2.10 and 2.11.

It worked for me when I updated the scala version of my project like below:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

and I updated my dependency like:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.4.0",
```

If you use "%%", sbt will add your project’s binary Scala version to the artifact name.

From sbt run:

```
sbt> reload
sbt> compile
```

Answer (score 1):

Your library dependecy conflicts with with the scala version you're using, you need to use 2.11 for it to work. The correct dependency would be:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.4.1"
```

note that you need to change spark_parent to spark_core

Comment: Correct. Or he can just double the first `%` operator and remove `_2.11` (well except there's no 2.11 version for Spark-parent on central)

Answer (score 0):

name := "SparkLearning"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.3"

// additional libraries
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.4.1"

Comment: I am using Intellij2017.2 community version and it's working for me