# Split and filter the column of data frame in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working with apache spark. I have the following txt file.

```
05:49:56.604899 00:00:00:00:00:02 > 00:00:00:00:00:03, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 10202: 10.0.0.2.54880 > 10.0.0.3.5001: Flags [.], seq 3641977583:3641987719, ack 129899328, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432619], length 10136
05:49:56.604908 00:00:00:00:00:03 > 00:00:00:00:00:02, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.3.5001 > 10.0.0.2.54880: Flags [.], ack 10136, win 153, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432623], length 0
05:49:56.604900 00:00:00:00:00:02 > 00:00:00:00:00:03, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 4410: 10.0.0.2.54880 > 10.0.0.3.5001: Flags [P.], seq 10136:14480, ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432619], length 4344
```

Now I would like to extract the IPs and time stamp from the file. For example the output should become like below:

```
05:49: 56.604899 10.0.0.2 54880 10.0.0.3 5001
05:49: 56.604908 10.0.0.3 5001 10.0.0.2 54880
05:49: 56.604900 10.0.0.2 54880 10.0.0.3 5001
```

Here is the code that I used:

```
object ML_Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("saeed_test").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("column0", StringType, true),
      StructField("column1", StringType, true),
      StructField("column2", StringType, true)))

    val df = sqlContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
      .schema(customSchema)
      .load("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/train.csv")

    val selectedData = df.select("column0", "column1", "column2")
    selectedData.write
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .save("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/tempoutput.txt")
  }
}
```

However I could just extract the following result. (I also could not apply split function here)

```
column0                                                  column1              column2
05:29:59.546965 00:00:00:00:00:01 > 00:00:00:00:00:03  ethertype IPv4 (0x0800) 05:29:59.546965 00:00:00:00:00:01 > 00:00:00:00:00:05
05:29:59.546986 00:00:00:00:00:01 > 00:00:00:00:00:03  ethertype IPv4 (0x0800)  length 66: 10.0.0.1.5001 > 10.0.0.3.43906: Flags [.]
05:29:59.546986 00:00:00:00:00:01 > 00:00:00:00:00:03  ethertype IPv4 (0x0800)  length 66: 10.0.0.1.5001 > 10.0.0.3.43906: Flags [.]
```

Can you help me to modify this code to do the above result. Please help me.

**Update1:** 
As I try to execute the answer number one, some fields can not recognize in my idea:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I added the following library and the problem get solved:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

**Update2:**
According to answer number one, as I ran the code in my idea, I got an empty folder as result. (Process finished with exit code 1)
The errors are:

```
       17/05/24 09:45:52 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at ML_Test$$anonfun$2.apply(ML_Test.scala:28)
    at ML_Test$$anonfun$2.apply(ML_Test.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/05/24 09:45:52 ERROR DefaultWriterContainer: Task attempt attempt_201705240945_0000_m_000001_0 aborted.
17/05/24 09:45:52 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at ML_Test$$anonfun$2.apply(ML_Test.scala:28)
    at ML_Test$$anonfun$2.apply(ML_Test.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:258)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Please import `Row` library `import org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

Comment: Can you post all the error lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following can be your solution

```
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("column0", StringType, true),
  StructField("column1", StringType, true),
  StructField("column2", StringType, true)))

val rdd = sc.textFile("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/train.csv")
val rowRdd =rdd.map(line => line.split(">")).map(array => {
  val first = Try(array(0).trim.split(" ")(0)) getOrElse ""
  val second = Try(array(1).trim.split(" ")(6)) getOrElse ""
  val third = Try(array(2).trim.split(" ")(0).replace(":", "")) getOrElse ""
  Row.fromSeq(Seq(first, second, third))
})

val dataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, customSchema)

val selectedData = dataFrame.select("column0", "column1", "column2")
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
selectedData.write
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/tempoutput.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However as I try to execute your code, some errors occur. I have just updated the question and put the error there. I think it is because of libraries and independencies , am I right?

Comment: you have to import a library `import org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

Comment: I use intellij idea and I can not find the library! According to this, there is some problem in versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265343/intellij-idea-14-cannot-resolve-symbol-spark

Comment: For the library I searched org.apache.spark.row, but I could not find any thing!

Comment: Its capital R. and its `sql` in middle And what are you using maven or sbt?

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code ran but the result is an empty folder! I have updated the question agin. (Update2) Could you please check it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post all the error lines? Did you try to see if `RDD` or `DataFrame` in between `read` and `write` has data with `rdd.foreach(println)` or `dataFrame.show(false)`? And please post all the error lines. The code ran successfully in mine, all I did was change the input and output path.

Comment: I should thanks for your patience. I am completely new in Spark. I have updated the question and added all errors to it.

Comment: its because your output file already exists, you need to delete that first

Comment: Even if I delete the output, again more errors occurs. I have updated the errors again in the question.

Comment: You should be using `Try` `getOrElse` in that case. I have updated my answer. please try that. Your input data is not constant . So you are getting ArrayIndexOutofBoundException errors

Comment: I have updated my answer again. Now you don't need to delete the output directory everytime you run . It will overwrite. Please take the update. And let me know if problem exists

Comment: Thanks a lot. but the program has minor error: Error:(22, 7) ')' expected but 'val' found.
      val third = Try(array(2).trim.split(" ")(0).replace(":", "") getOrElse ""

Comment: it seems you didn't see the updated answer. i had missed the ending bracket last time. it should work now. you can copy paste it and change the input and output path.

Comment: Thanks, yes I saw it, I have done it, but functions "createDataFrame", "fromSeq", "select" and "write" are not recognizable for the idea. I should insert a new library?

Comment: Do you need help on that?

Comment: well, I am searching on it. I think I can fix it.  Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Great to hear that @saeedtalaee. And thanks for upvoting. An upvote for your question too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you needed. This may not be the most effective solution but it works.

```
  val spark =
    SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val customSchema = StructType(
    Array(StructField("column0", StringType, true),
          StructField("column1", StringType, true),
          StructField("column2", StringType, true)))

  val data = spark.read
    .schema(schema = customSchema)
    .csv(
      "tempoutput.txt")

  data
    .withColumn("column0", split($"column0", " "))
    .withColumn("column1", split($"column2", " "))
    .withColumn("column2", split($"column2", " "))
    .select(
      $"column0".getItem(0).as("column0"),
      $"column1".getItem(3).as("column1"),
      $"column2".getItem(5).as("column2")
    )
    .show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but the idea found error in $. Is there any special library to add?